# How can $2\pi/\omega = T$, when it is equal to $\lambda/v$?

Tags: waves, notation

I can conceptually understand that $2π/$angular frequency will result in the period. $2π$ represents a full cycle, and $\omega$ represents the angle per second of the wave. Then, it follows that a total cycle/the number of waves a second represents the period.

However, substituting $\omega=2\pi v/\lambda$, where $v =$ frequency, into $T=2\pi/\omega$, the equation simplifies to $T=v/\lambda$. As far as I was aware, $T$ is only $1/v$, and not $\lambda/v$. Where is the incorrect assumption I am making?

Comment: This post (v2) exemplifies why one shouldn't substitute Greek letters with lookalike Roman letters :)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. Also, it helps catch errors like this one ;) (see QMechanic's comment) Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, $v$ (Latin letter vee) is velocity and $\nu$ (Greek letter nu) is frequency. You should have $T=1/\nu$ or $T=\lambda/v$, not $T=1/v$ or $T=\lambda/\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have confused the frequency with the velocity of light